# How to set the value into 0 when there's no input in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid

how to segregate the data and display the `PRN` children based on the `date` for example `january` then if there's a data which is `machine 1` then have `assetCode: PRN` it will display on the children header and then it will display the value if there's another `machine 2` then have `assetCode: PRN1` it will added on `january` children. then if the `machine 1` have no `assetCode: PRN1` then it will set at `0`, same as `machine 2`

here's the code:

***list.component.ts***

```
rowData = [
{
      code: "Machine 1",
      assetCode: "PRN",
      assetCount: 1,
      date: "2019-01-18 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      code: "Machine 1",
      assetCode: "PRN",
      assetCount: 1,
      date: "2019-01-19 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      code: "Machine 2",
      assetCode: "PRN 1",
      assetCount: 3,
      date: "2019-01-20 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      code: "Machine 3",
      assetCode: "PRN",
      assetCount: 1,
      date: "2019-01-21 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      code: "Machine 4",
      assetCode: "PRN 1",
      assetCount: 3,
      date: "2019-01-22 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      code: "Machine 5",
      assetCode: "PRN 1",
      assetCount: 3,
      date: "2019-01-23 00:00:00"
    }
];
this.columnDefs.push(
      {
        'headerName': 'Style/Machine',
        'field': 'code',
        'pinned': 'left',
        'lockPosition': true
      }
    );

    for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

      const record = {
        'headerName': this.monthNames[i].monthName,
        'children': [
          {
            'headerName': 'Total',
            'columnGroupShow': 'closed'
             'field': 'total'
          }
        ]
      };

record.children.push(
          {
            'headerName': 'PRN',
            'columnGroupShow': 'open'
             'field': 'assetCount'
          }
);
this.columnDefs.push(record);
}
```

How to make it like this.

[image]

Comment: Could you please add a raw data you use to fill in the ag-grid rows?

Comment: @kamil-kubicki done updating

Answer (score 2):

Analysing your code and data you have enclosed to the issue, it seems it won't work miraculously together.
Both require slight changes in order to generate the grid you want.

In the code, you use 'Column Groups' to structure the display, however your grid headers 'PRN,...,PRNX' are strongly based on data object
attributes 'assetCode' and 'assetCount' - that is why easier way is to consider ag-grid 'Pivoting' as solution for given problem.

> Pivoting allows you to take a columns values and turn them into columns.

1. Firstly we'll need to define the structure for all the 'Machines X' rows:

```
{
  code: "Machine X",
  PRN:  1,
  PRN1: 5,
  PRN2: 7,
  ...
  PRNX: XX,
  month: "January"
},{
  code: "Machine X",
  PRN:  1,
  PRN1: 3,
  ...
  PRNX: XX,
  month: "February"
},
```

2. Second step consists on setting the configuration for the columns totals hould be calculated for (PRN headers will be created together with data transformation in later step):

```
var gridOptions = {
    ...
    //Switched to true to b 'Pivot' feature
    pivotMode: true, 
    //Switched to true, so headers won't include the aggFunc, eg 'sum(PRN)'
    suppressAggFuncInHeader: true,
    //Additional properties to define how your groups are displayed
    autoGroupColumnDef: {
        headerName: "Style/Machine", 
        field: "code", 
        width: 200,
        cellRendererParams:{
          suppressCount: true,
        },
    },
    //Helps display & ordering by name of pivot headers
    processSecondaryColGroupDef: function(colGroupDef) {
      var res = colGroupDef.headerName.split("_");
      var month = monthNames[res[0]];
      colGroupDef.headerName = month+'\''+res[1];
    },
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: null
};
```

Main header for groupings:

```
{ headerName: "Code",  field: "code", rowGroup: true}
```

To pivot rows by a 'month' column define 'pivot: true':

```
 { headerName: "Month", field: "month", pivot: true},
```

3. In next step transform your input data to fit our structure from Step 1:

```
//Group the data per month/year for each 'Machine X'
var dataByMonthYear = rowData.reduce(function(dataByMonthYear, datum){
  var date  = new Date(datum.date);
  var year  = ('' + date.getFullYear()).slice(-2);
  
  //Index helps to aggregate the values by unique 'Machine_month_data' code
  var index = datum.code+'_'+date.getMonth() + '_' + year;
  
  //Init new entry
  if(!dataByMonthYear[index]){
     dataByMonthYear[index] = {code: datum.code, month: date.getMonth() + '_' + year};
  }
  if(!dataByMonthYear[index][datum.assetCode]){
     dataByMonthYear[index][datum.assetCode] = 0;
  }

  //Sum total by assetCode
  dataByMonthYear[index][datum.assetCode] += datum.assetCount;

  //Add PRN code to list (for later headers init)
  if(columns.indexOf(datum.assetCode) === -1){
     columns.push(datum.assetCode);
  }

  return dataByMonthYear;
}, {});

//Build final data - object to array
var finalRowData = Object.keys(dataByMonthYear).map(function(group){
  return dataByMonthYear[group];
});
```

4. Last thing to do is to set the columns

```
//Global structure of PRN header:
{ 
    headerName: "PRN", field: "PRN", 
    //Custom aggregate function, replacing default aggFunc: 'sum',
    //to handle 0 values for not present attributes
    aggFunc: customAggFunction
},
```

And the main function responsible for counting & column defining:

```
function customAggFunction(values) {
   var sum = 0;
   values.forEach( function(value) {
        if (typeof value === 'number') {
            sum += value;
        }
    });
    return sum;
}

//Define PRN columns 
columns.map(function(col){
  columnDefs.push({ headerName: col, field: col, aggFunc: customAggFunction
     });
});
```

Please note that another solution would be using full groups instead of pivoting, however we would need to define one column for each *YEAR_MONTH_PRN* to display all values, handle filtering & sorting etc. (for display of several years with lots of PRN's this solution is slghtly heavier then).

[Working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/v0YELn3pp06uVYVHKRad?p=preview)

> After the comments:
>
> "if in month of march there's PRN 1 it will display, but if there's no PRN in month of march it should display."

The second solution will be more relevant for you as pivot columns are shared and what you need is full access to the column definition to show/hide
them regarding the total value of given period. That means we need to create as many columns as `accessCodes` in your source data.

Please note that rows without an `accessCode` in original data will have values assigned and set to 0 - to do so we need to map all the possible columns for 'assetCode/month/year' present in the data source then create them for each row (this will avoid blank values for missing columns).

Please note that second solution is not optimal one as need to go through data twice - once to map all the columns and second time to assign the values for each row. If there wouls be a way to get from server side the list of periods ('assetCode/month/year'), that would improve the code.

[Working example v2](https://plnkr.co/edit/o9X51hfm0gJLPYxgsbrO?p=preview)

Comment: from the example

Comment: in month march there's no PRN it shouldn't display the PRN

Comment: if in month of march there's PRN 1 it will display, but if there's no PRN in month of march it should display.

Comment: the column for 0 counting shouldn't remove. it will not leave blank instead it should be 0

Comment: @ABC - updated ater last comment - 0 values are injected for all columns without values and columns displayed if exists in the data source for given period.

Comment: can you create on stackblitz?

Comment: How to display the other months? it should display to jan to dec

Comment: ```StyleForecastComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'PRN_4_19' of undefined```